# Badge-rendering Incorrect in Opera - Single line solution

Tags: feature-request, badges, design

`-moz` and `-webkit` are both declared for the border-radius of the `.badge` class, but neither of these render in Opera. For these, we need to add the general rule:

```
border-radius:6px;
```

This will reconcile the rendering between Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Opera ... isn't that something you go to fall asleep at?

Comment: "I told you to slow down! On account of you I nearly heard the opera!" -- Groucho Marx to the cab driver